# Can I call a global function inside a mustache.js template?

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

```
    <script>
        function fun() {
          console.log("fun was called");
          return "fun result";
        }
    </script>

    <script id="template" type="text/template">            
         test: {{window.fun()}}            
    </script>
```

In this example, fun() gets never called. Is it possible to call a **global** function?

Comment: seems like handlebars is the answer.

Comment: "One of our major motivations in writing Handlebars.js rather than just using mustache.js was to allow users to define global helpers." http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handlebars.js was the solution.